# How to overwrite public files in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've started to pass new guide about chat on `firebase`. I did some commits and deploys.

Then I've fixed that issue in alert message, to enable storage. Changed files and made '`firebase` deploy' - files are not overwritten. So no changes on hosting won't happen. How to overwrite those files?
[This app](https://fir-chat.firebaseapp.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command with a `--debug` option to see a verbose output of your command.

> $ `firebase deploy --debug`

It will output the handshake (request, response) to the server also. Good for knowing what is going on when authorizing your deploy.